# Dynamodb update table data not working

Tags: php, amazon-dynamodb

I want to update data using 'typeId', 'type_id' is not a primary key.

While this code is work, if we use other primary key.

Unable to update record.

getting following error :

```
{"__type":"com.amazon.coral.validate#ValidationException","message":"The provided key element does not match the schema"}

 $response = $this->dbo->updateItem([
            'TableName' => $this->tableName,
            'Key' => [
                'typeId' => ['S' => "qtwr234"]
            ],
            'ExpressionAttributeValues' => [
                ':val1' => ['N' => '1']
            ],
            'UpdateExpression' => 'set count = :val1',
            'ReturnValues' => 'ALL_NEW'
        ]);
```

Comment: Could you show the table's schema?

Comment: Partition key and sort key (if present) are must to update the item.

Answer (score 1):

According the error message you're receiving

> This error occurs when your key (**hash / primary key**) doesn't not match in parameters your passing to update the data in table.

**Solution :**

1. Run listTables commands and check for key element you created while creating elements.
2. Now, replace that key element in query parameters.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks. I have to update data on columId which is not a primary key